# Why removing a node from a linkedlist comes with O(1)?

Tags: algorithm

I am reading a book and it says that the normal deletion with traversal is O(n). Ok it's easy. But then it says that if you just copy the data from the next node to our node it will make it O(1).

Here on Stackoverflow I read another explanation for that, but I still don't understand it. Don't we still have to locate the nodes?

Here are the nodes, the data stored is in parentheses:

```
N("cop")->N("cat")->N("dog")->N("snake")->N("soldier")->N("camel")->N("ghost")->N("rock")
```

How is deleting the node (or moving the data from the next node) with "soldier" done in O(1)?
How is it possible to just point on it and say it is the soldier node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually who talks about linked list deletion on `O(1)`  assume that you got a pointer to node itself and not just the value of it, hence you don't need to traverse the list.

Answer (score 3):

Well I think you are confusing two different things: searching for the node by content and removing the node.

You refer to a node by a pointer (you can call it an iterator, handle, link, ...), and you can remove it by setting its `next` link and its data to the ones from the next node - done in O(1).

Only if you don't have a pointer to it, you search for it - which is O(n).